# How to fix icons and text in programs that suddenly enlarged, on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, display, icons

A few days ago, my desktop icons and certain text in programs (eg the text in my Mozilla Firefox toolbars) suddenly enlarged, but I changed nothing. To confirm this uncontrolled suddenness, I  just checked that all inputs in the following have remained unchanged:

Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display\Screen Resolution
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display

How do I fix or revert this sudden enlargement? The screenshot below shows this problem: the red arrows pinpoint the wrongfully enlarged text, in the toolbars and Bookmarks tab. The green arrows pinpoint the original (and correct) smaller text, in the URL, Tab title, and Bookmarks toolbar.

[image]

Comment: Just checking: under Display there's "Change only the text size", how much is "Title bars" at, 11? Apply it to, let's say 9 and then back to 11 and see if that helped. I'm saying this because even after I've changed mine from 11 and applied, it still showed me 11 even though I had 9.

Comment: @derpoholic Thanks for the suggestion. Originally, it was set at 18, but I don't know why. I then changed it to 11, and afterwards again to 9, but nothing appears differently. The problem above still persists. So now, the size is 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the size of your Menus like you've shown, Goto:

Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display

Check the *Let me choose one scaling....* option.
Under *Change only the text size* select **Menus** from the dropdown list and choose your new size (9 is default). Similarly you can select *Icons* and change them (9 is default).

Comment: Thanks. I've read and am currently trying your answer, but Wins requires me to restart every time. I shall heed the deadline for the bounty, but please message me if I forget.

Comment: @LePressentiment - Did it work?

Comment: Thank you. Yes. Sorry about the delay, but bounty duly rewarded.

Answer (score 2):

Personal experience:
"Sudden" size change of desktop items (and web browser content) comes from
holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and rolling the mouse wheel.