# How can I return larger-than-normal UI text to its original size?

Tags: windows-8.1, desktop

A couple days ago, text and buttons in title bars, menu bars, context menus, and even file names in explorer (and on desktop) became about 40% larger than they were before.

I'm not sure what caused this, as I didn't change any settings. Just turned off my computer one day, turned it on the next, and it's been like this since.

[image: Enlarged desktop text]

My machine is a laptop with a touchscreen, screen resolution of 1366x768 px. It's really driving me crazy; how can I get this text back to its original size? (I can provide any additional screenshots/info as needed.)

Comment: have your DPI settings been changed? the standard default is 96 DPI. http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/443-dpi-display-size-settings-change.html

Comment: @FrankThomas, nope, just checked and they are still at 96 DPI as usual.

Comment: Has the screen resolution changed? Right-click on the desktop background, select *Screen Resolution*, and check if it's been altered (as might happen if you've used the machine with another monitor or projector).

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, it hasn't; the screen resolution is 1366x768, I don't ever change it.

Comment: Well, looks like I've found the answer at http://superuser.com/a/928116/462210 Somehow the "Change only text size" option was altered from default for the menus (9px), title bars (12px), and icons (9px).

Comment: As a follow-up for future reference, what is causing the unexpected zoom is the Lenovo energy manager's zoom feature. When fn and + or - is pressed, the size of several UI elements is altered, and the title bars (on my system at least) must be changed back through the change only text size option, as they are reset back to 11px, not 12px.